# Set up bluetooth tethering windows 8 with galaxy s3

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, android, tethering

I'm looking instructions to tether my windows 8 laptop via Bluetooth with my Samsung Galaxy s3 android.

I've enabled Bluetooth Tethering on the Samsung Galaxy S3.
I've paired the devices on windows, but I'm unsure what the next step is.

My version of Windows is 8.1

I can't use portable hotspot as the WIFI on my laptop is broken (I was previously using this).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your Laptop has proper Bluetooth driver installed, and "Bluetooth PAN" under network adapter is enabled.

You just go to "`Device and Printer`", pick your paired Galaxy S3, right click and select `Connect using` -> `Access point`.

Comment: And if I don't have the drivers...?